# How to add a value to specific columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to perform the same arithmetic operation on specific columns of a pandas DataFrame. I do it as

```
c.loc[:,'col3'] += cons
c.loc[:,'col5'] += cons
c.loc[:,'col6'] += cons
```

There should be a simpler approach to do all of these in one operation. I mean updating `col3,col5,col6` in one command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) label indexing accepts lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df.loc[:, ['B', 'C']] += 10

print(df)

   A   B   C
0  1  12  13
1  4  15  16
```